# Automate Win8 network and sharing settings

Tags: windows-8, deployment, sysprep, unattended

I am trying to create a unattended DVD installation of Windows 8, but I can't seem to find a solution do this.

What I'm looking for are to have the same settings on the Network and Sharing Center, to have the `Turn on network discovery` "on" for both the private and guest/public within the Control Panel.

For private and guest/public, I need to:

- Turn on network discovery
- Turn on printer and file sharing
- Turn off public folder sharing
- Turn on password protected sharing
- Use user accounts and passwords to connect to other computers

I've been searching for days and have not found a solution yet.

Comment: In the firewall you mean? Or on certain SSID names? Will the user be an Administrator when they connect?

Comment: What I'm looking for are the same settings on the Network and Sharing Center, to have the Turn on network discovery "on" for both the private and guest/public at the control panel gui.

Comment: OK, can you please [edit] that into the question? It will make it easier for other experts to be able to answer it.

Comment: I Guess there's not easy way to do this, the only way I have found that would do some of what I am asking is the following. netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Network Discovery" new enable=Yes

netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="File and Printer Sharing" new enable=Yes

Comment: If you found the solution, post it as an answer, instead of a comment. This way, other users can see that there is an answer here. You will need to expand on what you did to make that work though, so it's useful to other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Guess there's not easy way to do this, the only way I have found that would do some of what I am asking is the following.

- netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Network Discovery" new enable=Yes
- netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="File and Printer Sharing" new enable=Yes

But it only does some of what I need. But so far it works.